# Problem retrieving a list of posts for an html view in php

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I'm trying to use php build a blog website where all the posts are publicly available, but somehow I'm having issues getting the posts to actually display on the page.

The code for the query is:

```
<?php
    class Blog {
        private $db;
        
        public function __construct(){
            $this->db = new Database;
        }

        public function getBlogs(){
            $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM posts');
            $results = $this->db->resultSet();

            return $results;
        }

    }
```

The code for generating the view is:

```
public function __construct(){
           
            $this->blogModel = $this->model('Blog');
        }


        public function index(){
            // Get posts

            $posts = $this->blogModel->getPosts();

            $data = [
                'posts' => $posts
            ];

            $this->view('pages/blog', $data);
        }
```

And the actual HTML for the view looks like this:

```
<?php require APPROOT . '/views/inc/header.php'; ?>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">    
            <h1>Artículos</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php foreach($data['posts'] as $post) : ?>
        <div class="card card-body mb-3 mt-3">
            <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $post->title; ?></h4>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/posts/show/<?php echo $post->postId; ?>" class="btn button-custom-orange">More</a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php require APPROOT . '/views/inc/footer.php'; ?>
```

However, when I actually try to go to pages/blog, I get a **Notice: Undefined index: posts in C:\xampp\htdocs\edutechne\app\views\pages\blog.php on line 7**, meaning that the array is apparently not being passed to the view.

Any idea what might be wrong with my code?

EDIT: Someone asked that I include the code for the view so here it is:

```
public function view($view, $data = []){
         // Check for view file
         if(file_exists('../app/views/' . $view . '.php')){
            require_once '../app/views/' . $view . '.php';
         } else {
             // View does not exist
             die('View does not exist');
         }

     }
```

Comment: I don't know what kind of framework you are using, but most likely you need to do `foreach ($posts as $post)`, because you never actually pass `data` to view, it's just name of your variable

Comment: value is not  set  in $data['posts']

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72113999/edit) your post please to add the code from the function `$this->view()`, or if you are using a third-party framework to render the template then state which one.

Comment: @Dotsquares how do I set the value? I'm just learning PHP at the moment so still a bit lost on how this all works

Comment: This looks alot like CodeIgniter and @Justinas is right, you need to use `$posts` in `foreach` instead of `$data['posts']`

Comment: I did try that, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: It would be helpful if you could name the code snippets with the according file name. Like what code comes from what file? I know see, that the third code belongs to the $view.php you are refering to in the 4. code area.

Besides that try to do "quick-debug": Add a var_dump($data) in the particular view-file, before the loop and before the inclusion of the header.php, to see if the array actually contains data.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround and maybe a cleaner way of coding would be declaring the $data array as a property:

```
    class Blog {
        private $db;
        private $data;
        ...
```

Within your construction method you may now initiate the array like that:

```
    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Database;
        $this->data = ['posts' => ['no posts']]
    }
```

(The actual value depends on your data structure, passing a default value is not a bad idea. I just assumed an array holding one item 'no posts')

Within your index method you pass the results to the property:

```
    public function index(){
        ...
        $this->data['posts'] = $posts
        ...
```

Now you do not need to pass the $data to the method $Blog->view(), you can address it within. Remove the argument from the method declaration:

```
public function view($view){
   ...
```

And modify your for-each-loop like that:

```
<?php foreach($this->data['posts'] as $post) : ?>
```

But heads up: This way you need to make sure to properly populate and clean up the $data-property. It's now kind of persistant within the class instance.

Answer (score -2):

I am not used to this way of coding in php, but to me it looks like your function named index is reason you can't get what you need. Try adding `return $data` to your code so it looks like this:

```
public function index(){     

            $posts = $this->blogModel->getPosts();

            $data = [
                'posts' => $posts
            ];

            $this->view('pages/blog', $data);
            return $data;
        }
```

Comment: That didn't help, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: can you also try <?php foreach($data as $post) {
        echo"<div class='card card-body mb-3 mt-3'>
            <h4 class='card-title'>". $post['title']."</h4>
            <a href="; echo URLROOT; echo"/posts/show/".$post['postId']." class='btn button-custom-orange'>More</a>
        </div>";

Comment: Well... it stopped giving me the error, but now nothing displays on the screen. It's definitely something wrong with the back-end, somehow the array is not being passed on to the view but I can't figure out why not